# FileDataStoreFinder.getDataStore() returns null Pointer

Tags: java, maven, geotools

I'm trying to recreate the GeoTools [QuickStart](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/quickstart/intellij.html) tutorial.

Maven integration worked fine, now i want to load a german postcode to area [shapefile](http://www.metaspatial.net/download/plz.tar.gz). My code is as follows:

```
File file = new File("\\PATH\\TO\\FILE\\post_pl.shp");
FileDataStore store = FileDataStoreFinder.getDataStore(file);
SimpleFeatureSource featureSource = store.getFeatureSource();
```

The `FileDataStoreFinder` always returns null when calling `getDataStore()`. Debugging it suggests it can't find anything in `GeoTools.scanForSystemHints(newGlobal);`.

The shapefile can be read by other viewers without problems. The path in java is also correct. It also fails on the example files from the tutorial. Can I maybe include the .dbf and .shx files?

I also tried downgrading the sdk from 1.9 to 1.8 (as the [doc](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/build/install/jdk.html#using-java-9-with-geotools) implies problems), but to no avail, still a null pointer.

Can anyone help me identify my error, or have some input on what I might check?

Thanks for your help

Thomas

Comment: try using `/` instead of `\\` and if the path is absolute include the drive letter,

Comment: Still the same null exception, but thanks :(

Comment: can you add the stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using netbeans, you may be missing the dependency in your pom.xml file. Add the dependency and verify that the geotools versioning attribute is correct.

```
</project>
    </repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>osgeo</id>
            <name>Open Source Geospatial Foundation Repository</name>
            <url>http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-shapefile</artifactId>
            <version>${geotools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Source: Had the problem, found this unanswered question, fixed it; felt compelled to make my first post to contribute when I solved it.